# Where to find USA river drainage data as shapefile in R

Tags: geospatial, usa, hydrology

I'm looking for a shapefile of all major river drainages in the USA. Something similar to this in R:

[image]

Specifically, I need the Arizona/New Mexico boundaries but probably could zoom in from the US shapefile...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to start with https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/ where you can find *Rivers, Lake Centerlines* and/or *Lakes + Reservoirs* datasets. The other option is OpenStreetMap data, available at https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america.html, however it requires a bit of preprocessing.